# Reasons for buying ASN for organisation that are located at single place

Tags: routing, router, bgp, networking, isp

I see [here](https://www.whatismyip.com/asn/IN/) that even some organisation/universities have bought [ASN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)) which are located at single location. What benefit they will get by buying ASN ?  Is it compulsory to buy ASN if I have to buy some public IP's from my ISP ?

Example :

[Shiv Nadar University](https://www.whatismyip.com/asn/132785/) etc

Comment: Organizations get ASNs when they need to exchange routes via BGP with other organizations.

Comment: Thnx @RonMaupin but why would anyone want to do it ? They can get the routing info by connecting their router to ISP router too and ISP router can BGP with other

Comment: You are looking at this from a home networking perspective, where the home network uses an address from the ISP. If the organization wants to advertise its networks via BGP to the ISP and the greater world, then it needs an AS number. Thje organization could also have multiple connections to various ISPs (this is a normal situation), and it would like to choose the best path out.

Comment: Also, remember that the original ISPs were universities. The Internet originated from a government/university experiment.

Comment: Thnx @RonMaupin . One doubt though as you said - `If the organisation wants to advertise its networks via BGP to the ISP..` , why would an org be interested in that ? Will ISP pay some money to it for that ? I get the other reason of multiple ISP as you mentioned.

Comment: Most large organizations own their own IP networks, and they must advertise those networks so that people outside can get to the networks. If Google did not advertise its networks to the various providers, you could not get to Google because there would be no path to Google networks. The same applies to a university. If you wanted to get to the university network (web site, etc.), the Internet must know how to get packets to the university, so the university network(s) must be advertised out to the Internet.

Comment: @RonMaupin ok but why we need to be plugged into some BGP router for *advertising* of my network to outside world . For sole purpose fo advertising , any router plugged into any other router will do the needful. Please correct me if I am wrong. What benefit an organisation will get by advertisement of their network  *through BGP* ?

Comment: BGP is the routing protocol of the Internet (there has to be one, and it is BGP by agreement). If you want to advertise your networks to the rest of the world, and a business does so that the rest of the world can connect to it, then you must use BGP. If you own you own IP addressing, then even your directly connected ISP(s) need to know what it is, and you tell them about it through BGP. That is the only way the Internet can know to send traffic addressed to you to your ISP(s) that can then send it to you. That is routing 101.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

An Autonomous System number (ASN) is required to use the BGP protocol.  An organization can get a registered ASN, or it can use a private ASN (similar in concept to private IP addresses).

ISPs use BGP to exchange routing information with other entities.  So if your organization wishes to exchange routes with your ISP, you will need to run BGP, and you will need an ASN.

If the routes you advertise are registered to you (*i.e.,* provider-independent space), you will need a registered ASN.  If you are using address space provided by your ISP, you may be able to use a private ASN.  That is something you would negotiate with your ISP.

An organization that has only a single connection to one ISP, in most cases, doesn't need to use BGP, and can simply use static routing.